# Imported Posts missing summary text on staging site

Tags: posts, import, staging

I used WP Settings' native export (from production site) and import (to staging site on subdomain) for several months' posts.

The imported posts are not showing a summary/excpert on the homepage feed. I've tried changed the Reading setting to Full Text and back to Summary, but it didn't have any effect.

This can be seen at staging.slowgetter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there's little chance that something went wrong, first of all make sure that you content is actually there. Just edit a post from your dashboard and make sure it looks like it should,

Now, it looks like you have different themes on you live and staging sites, so it most probably is an issue with your staging theme. It might have its own set of configuration options (check Appearance > Customize), or it might be a bug.

It's probably best to read the theme's documentation or contact the theme's author.

Comment: That worked: I went to Customize/Layout...Blog/Archive and changed the selection to Full Content from Excerpt. Thank you!